# Having internal server error in my nodejs code

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, server

i am currently having internal server error and i don't know why it occurs since i am a newbie in this field. Can anyone explain what is going on here and suggest me a possible way to fix my code ?.Oh, and off - topic a little, i don't know exactly what i have to do to be fluently in making a connection between nodejs server and ajax, can any one help me with that?. Please don't erase this. Thanks you a lot

Here is my nodejs server:

```
var express = require("express"),
        bodyParser = require("body-parser"),
        data = require("nedb");
    var app = express(),
        db = new data({filename:'infors'});
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:false}));
    app.use(bodyParser.json());
    app.use(express.static("public"));
    app.get("/",function(req,res){
        res.sendfile("html.html");
    });
    app.post("/login",function(req,res){
        var user = req.body.user,
            pass = req.body.pass;
        db.insert({user:user,pass:pass});
        res.end("login sucessful");
    });
    app.listen(3000);
```

Here is my html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
   <head>
   </head>
   <body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
    var user,pass;
    $("#button").click(function (){
        user = $("#text").val();
        pass = $("#text2").val();
        $.post("http://localhost:3000/login",{user:user,pass:pass},function(data){
            if(data == "done"){
                alert("login success");
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
<fieldset>
   <input type="text" id="text"/>
   <input type="text" id="text2"/>
   <input type="button" id="button" value="press here"/>
</fieldset>   
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please change to **db = data({filename:'infors'});** with **db = new data({filename:'infors'});**

Comment: oh actually, there is db = new data(); forget to write it in this post

Comment: What is the EXACT error you get, word for word and what line does it occur on?

Comment: Your `app.post("/login",...)` is what you need to do to listen for the ajax call `$.post("http://localhost:3000/login", ...)` so that part looks fine as is.

Comment: Your `res.end("login sucessful");` should be `res.send("login sucessful");`.

Comment: I don't know why you're checking `if(data == "done")` when you're sending `"login sucessful"` (which also happens to be misspelled).

Comment: Here is the right syntax for initializing DB **db = new data({filename:'./infors.db', autoload: true});** and it's working fine for me.

Comment: i have already told you, i am not familiar with all of the errors the console gives me, and when there is an error, it gives me like a list of directories which i find it hard to search for the exact where it occurs.

Comment: why i have to use res.send, i think that this is the end of request so i have to use res.end()

Comment: I recommend you `res.contentType('text/plain');` - when I used a minimal version of your code, jQuery seemed to "guess" that the response was XML and broke - but that's not the source of the internal error - it's something to do with the `db` as that's the only part I took out to test the rest of your logic

Comment: i do it so that i can easily check for it on the website without opening IDE

Comment: res.end is fine

Comment: I told you Anish Agarwal, i do write it in my file but i think that in my writing process, i have forgotten it

Comment: With the addition of `res.contentType('text/plain');` before `res.end` ... and changing the test condition to `if(data == "login sucessful"){` - your code works 100% ... with only a warning in the node console - `express deprecated res.sendfile: Use res.sendFile instead`

Comment: i still don't understand the part (express deprecated res.sendfile: Use res.sendFile instead) because if i change to res.sendFile, more problems will occur

Comment: if you change to `res.sendFile` you have to read the documentation for [res.sendFile](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.sendFile) and add the appropriate `options` parameter - `{root: __dirname + '/'}` should be enough to get you going again

Comment: Oh and Jaromanda X, can you suggest a solution for my problem in the off - topic part ?

Comment: No, because I don't understand what you mean by `fluently in making a connection`

Comment: I lack the ability to understand how things work during the request - response process since i don't have IDE for nodejs, i cannot pause, cannot inspect steps one by one, that's why i cannot analyse my mistakes such as this post. And still i am searching web but don't know where to start, i believe that this problem belongs to concept rather then coding

Comment: Directly from the [Express documentation for `res.end()`](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.end): ***Use to quickly end the response without any data. If you need to respond with data, instead use methods such as res.send() and res.json().***  It may work as is, but it would be better to use `res.send()` which also ends the response.

Comment: post the error code dear to make it more clear just copy that one and paste here

Comment: your probably having issues with `res.sendfile('html')`, consider using `sendFile` and full system path to the file. `res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'html.html'))`. Can you not see any errors when you start up your app in terminal?